# When to use "once-in-a-lifetime" and when to use "once in a lifetime"?

Tags: hyphenation

The first one has ***-*** connected and the others do not have, this two seem to have the same meaning but my teacher say not, what is the difference between them?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In general, hyphens are used to construct compound adjectives:

- I had to catch an early-morning train.
- I like late-night television.
- She wears extra-large socks.

Hyphens are not used when the words stand alone. So, to use your examples:

- It was a once-in-a-lifetime trip (a trip so special or expensive that one would be unlikely to undertake such a trip more than once, and once-in-a-lifetime acts as an adjective).
- We are born once in a lifetime (literally, this event happens exactly once, and the four words stand alone to describe that fact).